# Want to display data in desc order

Tags: php, yii, yii2-advanced-app

I want to display data in desc order.

```
->where(['listing_section.is_active' => 1])
->innerJoin(Translations::tableName(),'translations.parent_id=listing_section.id')
->andWhere(['translations.parent_tbl' => 'listing'])
->select('listing_section.keywords, listing_section.description, 
listing_section.slug, 
 translations.title,translations.short_text,translations.content');
```

Comment: Please, format your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the order like this..

```
->order = 'listing_section.date Desc';
```

`date` will be the column in your database, Whatever you have there, you can replace it.

you can also use `id` to show data in DESC or ASC order by id too.

```
->order = 'listing_section.id Desc';
```

..

```
->where(['listing_section.is_active' => 1])
->innerJoin(Translations::tableName(),'translations.parent_id=listing_section.id)
->andWhere(['translations.parent_tbl' => 'listing'])
->select('listing_section.keywords, listing_section.description, listing_section.slug, translations.title,translations.short_text,translations.content');
->order = 'listing_section.date Desc';
```

Update:

Simply you try to upgrade the php version. I've your same error with php 5.5, but with php 5.6 everything works fine.

Comment: Error (#4) An internal server error occurred. The above error occurred while the Web server was processing your request. Please contact us if you think this is a server error. Thank you.

Comment: Unknown Property
 when i execute that code then it will show error like this " An internal server error occurred.
The above error occurred while the Web server was processing your request.

Please contact us if you think this is a server error. Thank you."

Comment: Oh its because of Yii2, you should try to upgrade the php version to the latest. everything will work fine.